# How to get username with CherryPy digest authentication

Tags: python, http, authentication, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy application running successfully using the built-in digest authentication tool and no session support.  Now, I would like to expose additional features to certain users.  Is it possible to obtain the currently-authenticated user from the authorization system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use: [`cherrypy.request.login`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/_cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.login).

To quote:

> When authentication is used during the request processing this is set
>   to ‘False’ if it failed and **to the ‘username’** value if it succeeded.
>   The default ‘None’ implies that no authentication happened.

The whole HTTP Basic / Digest authentication in CherryPy is very nicely explained [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090222054041/http://jimhoskins.com/2008/07/21/cherrypy-digest-and-basic-authentication) (unfortunately the original blog no longer features this page, at least I couldn't find it - WayBack Machine to the rescue).

Answer (score 1):

Found the user name encoded in the HTTP request header Authorization.  I am able to parse it from there.  If there's a "better" place to obtain the username, I'm open to improvements!

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
params  = auth_header.split(" ", 1)
items = parse_http_list(params)
paramsd = parse_keqv_list(items)
username = paramsd.get('username')
```

http://www.gitorious.org/forban/forban/blobs/1f9aff12551675f7cd8395f8bd0733cfc4c40784/lib/ext/cherrypy/lib/auth_digest.py

As I looked at it more this approach still uses auth header...

Andrew

Comment: As expected, I get an error telling me I have no session.  The code you cite includes its own homegrown authentication system (and uses sessions); I'm trying to piggyback off of cherrypy.lib.auth_digest.